# Multiple events triggered in redisClient.on('message')

Tags: javascript, python, django, node.js, redis

I'm trying to communicate Django and Node.js through redis but when I try to get the on('message') event in Node.js i get the event 2 times...

I have this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

//Subscribe to chat channel
sub.subscribe('chat');

//Get the event 'message' from Django
sub.on('message', function(channel, message){
        console.log("counter");
    });
.
.
.
```

And I get "counter" printed 3 times and when I connect from another client, I get 4,5,6,...

How can I get the event ONLY ONCE?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're listening on the right channel

```
sub.on('message', function(channel, message){
    switch (channel) {
      case 'chat':
           console.log("counter");
           break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tryied that but it didnt work. I get "counter" 4 times. =( I dont know what should I do

Comment: Are you using clusters? that could explain why you are getting multiple console logs.

Answer (score 0):

You add a listener in the socket.io `connection` listener, so every time a new connection is opened you attach the listener again.  Just attach the `message` listener outside of the `connection` listener.